# Converting image from RGB color space to CMYK and removing ICC profile

Tags: color, gimp, cmyk

I generated several figures for a manuscript using Lucidchart and exported these figures as PDF. Because the journal I am submitting to requires images to be in CMYK color space, I used GIMP and the Cyan app/plugin (for OS X) to import the PDFs and export them as TIFs in CMYK color space.

The automated image checker for the journal is still giving me a warning because my exported TIFs "contain an embedded ICC (International Color Consortium) Profile. This attribute of the file needs to be removed for complete passage by DigitalExpert."

Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Adobe applications I could do this in no time, but it seems that you only use freeware, right? I have no idea how to do that. But another thing: Are you aware that by converting your PDFs to TIFs in a raster application you might be converting sharp vector graphics to raster graphics which won't print as clearly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can get a hold of the Adobe suite if necessary. I was under the impression that PDFs were superior, however when I submitted PDFs to the journal, the automated image quality checker flagged the PDFs as being under the quality threshold in addition to being in RGB colorspace and having an ICC profile, which led me to try TIF. The PDFs were exported directly from Lucidchart.

Comment: PDFs are not by definition superior quality. They can contain both sharp vector graphics and crappy pixelated raster images so it depends. If you zoom in as much as you can on the PDF, does the graphics still appear sharp or do you see pixels? If it's sharp no matter what, it's probably vector and will print sharper than a raster image like TIF which will be somewhat blurred in comparison no matter the resolution.

Comment: PDF is a container it can contain nearly anything. Wether what is contained is of good quality or not is up to what is in the container (you can put nice stuff in a box as well as junk). PDF isnt inherently better quality than anything else. Anyway before you can even begin to talk about better or worse quality you need to define what better is. Its perfectly possible that what you consider better is considered worse in another situation. Anyway you almost certainly do not want to use gimp for cmyk conversion and even more so if your input is a PDF file.

Comment: Understood. Thank you both for explaining. How would you go about this? My options for export from Lucidchart are PDF, PNG, JPEG, SVG, CSV of shape data.

Comment: Of the file types you mention only PDF and SVG can be vector. And of those only PDF can be CMYK. But it seems Lucidchart can't export a CMYK PDF? So you need some program than can open and edit the PDFs (or SVGs) and save in CMYK in a format you can then place in your layout application (that could very well be PDF, but also perhaps EPS). Or, if your layout application is capable of converting to CMYK on export, just place the RGB version and export to CMYK on export. Which layout application do you use?

Comment: PDF, but you should not use GIMP with PDF files because it rasterizes everything which kindof defeats the purpose of using a charting app in first place. Note that your requirements seem wierd as naked cmyk is meaningless.

Comment: @joojaa, except for perhaps if it's only black and you can live with some uncertainty about exactly how dark the tints get. I come across print providers who insists on "just CMYK - no profile" whatever that means. 

Comment: @Wolff yeah but feels a bit iffy. If you ever end up having any kind of dispute with a vendor like this you have problems. Its a bit like working without a contract. I mean my colors are uncertain even with a profile. Atleast im clear what i am doing. But besides if they have such requirement why dont they specify pdf X-1a then atleast you can identify the intended space without profiles.

Comment: @joojaa, because they don't really know what a color space is and are somehow stuck in the past?